# Android - best practice to re-publish an android app?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I just published my first app and already there are a bunch of mistakes so I need to republish it :)

What I did was export my code as unsigned .apk, then I coded the app using my key like this:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore mykey.keystore my.apk mykey
```

Then the system did its thing and all went well.

Now I went to the google play site to republish, clicked on the tab: "apk files" and then I am not sure what to do.

Should I de-activate the original apk? Or should I just upload the new apk with the same name?

I tried just uploading the new apk, but got this error:

```
The new apk's versionCode (1) already exists.
```

Which suggests I should delete the old apk, right? Or did I maybe forget a step somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the market is asking you to change your apk versionCode in the AndroidManifest.xml, that way it can recognize it as a new version of the app.

Comment: Just increment the versionCode in your manifest file, and set the new APK as the active one on the Developer Console. That'll work :-)

Comment: Thank you - its a whole number every time just for keeping track, correct?

Comment: And do I still need to run zipAlign after I sign the new .apk? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Before uploading the updated application, be sure that you have incremented the android:versionCode and android:versionName attributes in the  element of the manifest file.

from: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `versionCode` in the `Manifest.xml`. Make it 2, or greater than the previous `versionCode`. You should also update the `versionName` in the `Manifest`.

Than just de-activate the previous version, and activate the newly uploaded one.

Answer (score 0):

versionCode is your apk subsequent release number, where a release is what going to be published in Google Play